# Power adaptor seems to be outputting too high a voltage

Tags: power-supply, adapter, voltage

I'm in a country with an unreliable national electricity supply, where staff in the compound in which I live run a generator at certain hours if there's no national power.

Recently, the generator seems to have been outputting too much (light bulbs and fuses blowing, appliances breaking with burning smells) while the national power, when it's on, has seemed too low (light bulbs dimmer than usual, USB devices failing to charge if more than one is connected to one plug).

I wanted to check my more valuable DC appliances are safe, so, while national power is on, I checked the output of their adaptors using a multimeter:

- My laptop adapter seems fine: it's supposed to output 19V and is outputting something like 19.2V
- **My adaptor for a lithium polymer battery pack is outputting too much: it's supposed to be an 18V adaptor but it's outputting 20.5V** (and the battery itself says its maximum is 19V)

Why would this adaptor be outputting too high a voltage, and is there anything I can do about it? (Other than buying a voltage regulator for all my power outlets - they're hard to find and expensive out here, I intend to get one but would like something for the meantime, and also to understand under what circumstances what types of adaptors will output the wrong voltage like this)

---

To be clear - unlike most other power adaptor / voltage questions on this site, I'm using the manufacturer-provided adaptor, and I already know the impact of deviations in volts (dangerous if too high, likely to fail quietly if too low) and amps (simply goes unused if too high, might fail or struggle if too low).

Comment: It's likely because you're measuring its output when it's not under any load. What exactly is this device that you're describing as "a lithium polymer battery pack" and is the "adaptor" a charger?

Comment: Not 100% sure what the difference is - it's a block with a wall plug in the block and one cable leading to a DC barrel plug, whereas the laptop one is a plug connected to a block by a 3-pin connection then a second cable with the DC plug. [Here's the LiPo battery](http://www.amazon.com/Intocircuit-PC26000-Capacity-26000mAh-Smartphones/dp/B00BB5VQCE)

Comment: Then most likely the issue is that you're measuring the output when the charger isn't under any load. It's not unusual for the output voltage to rise 10% to 15% when it's disconnected.

Comment: After looking up the difference, I'm still not 100% sure but I think the former (for laptop) is an adaptor and the latter (for battery) is a charger

Comment: @David sounds like a good answer to me. Any idea how I can check the voltage when it is under load?

Comment: If you have a power resistor, that would do it. Even a 1K ohm, 1/4 watt resistor would be better than nothing. A small lamp might work.

Comment: I'm trying to test it but the generator is on now and, weirdly, if I plug this battery charger in to any wall socket, the power in the house goes out, then comes back on instantly once it's unplugged. Laptop adaptor, or any other plug e.g. a lamp has no problem. I think this issue is unrelated... But prevents me from testing!

Comment: That likely indicates that current is leaking to ground somewhere in the charger. Perhaps you're connecting one of its output pins to ground? Does it happen even if the charger isn't connected to anything else or only when you connect something to it?

Comment: Yeah, even with nothing connected to the charger. I put the charger in the wall, not connected to anything and bam, everything goes off. I pull it out or flick the plug switch and everything comes back on.

Comment: That's weird. Does the charger have a ground connection or does it just connect to the wall with two wires? That sounds like possibly a ground fault in the charger.